# iTunes Connect and Xcode 8: your app has changed to invalid binary

Tags: xcode, binary, app-store-connect

Last week, with Xcode 7, I was able to upload without any issue. But today I am getting the message your app has changed to invalid binary.

I have seen that now with Xcode 8 a new icon 20x20 2x and 3x is added. I added one, but still getting the error.

Does anyone had similar problem?

Comment: lot of users getting similar errors recently, has bitcode is ON ? Turn OFF bitcode, and try uploading it from Application Loader

Comment: Thanks for the info, did it, but with same result -> invalid binary

Comment: In my case, I wasted a lot of time because not checked email. When you got such error, Apple sent you email with description. I had next one: "This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data."

Comment: You are so right, it is important to read the mails :-). In my case it was: This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

After adding the key the app passed without any issue.

Comment: You're welcome! It will be great if you accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 42):

**Сheck your email!**

In my case, I wasted a lot of time because I did not check my email. When you get such an error, Apple sends you an email with it's description.

For example, this is what Apple sent me:

> "This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data."

Answer (score 0):

After days of wrestling with the same problem I finally got my app successfully submitted, but only after being on the phone with Apple Developer support.

A couple of things to keep in mind:

1. Make sure you set the Info.plist description keys for any entitlements. This is necessary for iOS apps. Mine was a macOS app, so this didn't apply.
2. Head over to iTunes Connect, and recreate all your provisioning profiles and code signing certificates if you're not 100% sure that they're valid. You can do it for both Developer and Distribution.
3. In Xcode, turn off automatic code signing for your app, and any build targets (you can try automatic code signing in Xcode after completing steps #2 and #4 but that wasn't what worked for me).
4. Go to Xcode preferences, and click your development team, and in the sheet that comes up, you should see some "Download" buttons beside the newly created (in iTunes Connect) code signing certificates and provisioning profiles. Click them all. And so you don't get confused in step #5, delete all the other stale provisioning profiles and code signing identities for this app.
5. In Build Settings for each of your targets, make sure that the Release build setting for code signing, and provision profile are set to the above newly created code signing certificate and provisioning profile.
6. Bump your build number.
7. Deep clean your project (Option-Shift-Command-K).
8. Archive build your app.
9. In the Organizer that opens up, select the newly archived app, and validate (it always validated, but I still would get Invalid Binary later).
10. Export the build and select the option "Save for Mac App Store Deployment" or similar.
11. When prompted, use the same Provisioning Profiles you used previously and save.
12. Open the .pkg in Application Loader which you can launch from Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader menu.

I was't getting any emails on the Invalid Binary issue. Instead, I was lucky enough to have set up my iPad with iTunes Connect, and so, like clock-work, I was getting notifications within a couple minutes of uploading the app: "Your app ... has changed to Invalid Binary."

If you don't get one of these Invalid Binary notifications, that's a good sign. Another 10-15 minutes later, I checked the iTunes Connect portal, and I could finally add the uploaded build and submit for review.

Comment: Update: Have released several updates of our app without issue, until today. With no entitlements, or code-signing, or provisioning profile changes, the upload always gives "Invalid Binary." Some are suggesting it maybe an Xcode 8.2.1 issue. I'm going to delete and reinstall Xcode. Others have had some success by deleting Xcode before installing a new version.

Answer (score 0):

After a while of searching, as a last-ditch effort I added *every possible 'NS...UsageDescription* into each of my target's Info.plist and this seems to have worked. After process of elimination, I deduced that it was either the ***NSAppleMusicUsageDescription*** or the ***NSFaceIDUsageDescription*** key-string pair that was preventing the upload from being successful so I just added them even though I don't use either in my project. I have also read on some other threads that something with a new version of Xcode required them to have the ***NSAppleMusicUsageDescription*** even though they didn't use anything related to Apple Music.